# USB 3.1 not appearing in Device Manager on Z370M board

Tags: usb-storage, usb-3.1-type-c

I've got the Gigabyte Z370M D3H Rev 1.0 Board with USB 3.1 Gen 1 support.
I have a USB 3.1 Docking Station (Mediasonic ProRaid USB 3.1 10Gbps Docking station) connected to it with WD Purple Drive.

I can only get max of 150MB/s average write speed to this drive, tests done by copying four Video files around 1.6GB each to this WD Purple Drive on USB 3.1 Connection (via USB C Port)

Checked my Device Manager and I Don't seem to have a USB 3.1 driver installed. 
[image]

But i've gone through and installed all the official drivers and even utilities of the Motherboard.

What could be the issue here? Or is it normal that the USB 3.1 does not appear in the list? Or could the USB 3.1 driver be the "Generic SuperSpeed USB hub"?

Comment: 150MB/sec with a SATA is decent, how much faster do you think, a SATA drive over USB should be?

Comment: im sure it's not the theoretical 5Gbps but i hope it is higher than this 150MB/sec. regardless though my question is about the 3.1 driver not appearing in my device manager